# How to find out IOPS disk usage by pod/container on k8s nodes?

Tags: kubernetes, aks

My vms have been hard hit by IOPS (Causing network errors and other strange behavior) and I wonder what of my pods is causing it (if any) - how can I find out? I couldn't find a clear tool providing this info. I'll be glad for any clues (Cluster running in AKS azure managed kubernetes service)

Comment: I use prometheus operator chart with helm

Answer (score 1):

Installing and running `iotop` on each host could be the easiest way to find out what process is generating the most IO.

Answer (score 0):

With Prometheus and cAdvisor (in GKE included within kubelet metrics), you can use *container_fs* metrics, and calculate pod IOPS with:

```
max by (pod, device)(rate(container_fs_reads_total{container!=""}[5m]))
max by (pod, device)(rate(container_fs_writes_total{container!=""}[5m]))
```